# return original array instead of modified array

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am adding an `userIndex` to my array of objects which is getting added, in the subsequent next map function i want to return the parent object instead of the 
modified users array

```
var object = {
   users: [{}, {}, {}, {}]
}

 @Effect()
    handleResult$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .map(action => action.payload)
        .mergeMap(params =>
            this.service.search(memberparams)
                .pipe(
                    map(res => res.users.map((child, i) => ({ ...child, userIndex: i }))),
                    map(res => new fAct.done(res)) // Here the res points to res.users, i want the res to original one(parent object)
                )
                .catch(error => of(new fAct.failure(error)))
        );
```

Comment: Hi, I don't think I understood. You want the `res` from your first `map` (inside `pipe`) to persist into your second `map` (inside `pipe` as well)?

Comment: @JoãoGhignatti: Yes, but now in the second map its res.users instead of res

Comment: let me know if my answer fit your needs, if it doesnt, let me know how and we can work together to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to persist your first `res` from first `map` into the second one (both inside `pipe`), BUT with `users` property updated to contain `userIndex` you can:

```
.pipe(
  map(res => {...res, users: res.users.map((child, i) => ({...child, userIndex: i}))}),
  map(res => // do something)
)
```

This uses spread operator to copy the whole `res` object, but overrides `users` property inside of it.

Comment: But the originalRes does not have the newly appended userIndex in it?

Comment: Oh, I see, you need the whole `res` from original `map` but with `users` proeprty inside of it updated to contain `userIndex`, right?